# Child model is coming up as null

Tags: c#, json

I have a base class as below:

```
class BaseModel 
{
    Model1 model1 { get; set; }

    List<string> a1 { get; set; }
    string a2 { get; set; }
}
```

And a model `Model1`:

```
class Model1  
{
    public BaseModel Parent { get; set; }

     List<string> b1 => Parent?.a1;
     string b2 => Parent?.a2;

     int b3 { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT**: this is the Json File from which the values should be populated:

```
{
    "a2": "abc.abc",
    "id": "123",   
    "a1": [
         "/str1",
         "/str2",
         "/str3"
    ]     
}
```

This is the code to access the JSON:

```
dynamic validData = DataProvider.GetTestData();
BaseModel m = validData?.ToObject<BaseModel>();

DataProvider:

public static JObject GetTestData()
{
   const string path = @"path/file.json";
   return JsonDataReader.Get(path);
}
```

I want to get the values of `BaseModel` in `Model1`, but they are populating as null. I think I am missing something in setting the value.

Can I please get help on what I am missing out?

Comment: This is supposed to be an EF Core question? Where is your Linq query? How are you saving & loading data?

Comment: Did you call Include on your query?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: I have not added a linq query. May be I am missing that. I am getting list a1 and string a2 into the modelBase through a Json file.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Sorry I did not get your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Then show the json file and your code that loads it. In which case this doesn't sound like an EF Core question so you should remove the tag.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman: Added the json and removed the tag as well.

Comment: The json provided here doesn't actually contain a "model1"

Comment: @ThomasKelly: Yes, the json will have List a1 and string a2. I want to get them in Model1.

Comment: You're loading as BaseModel, which contains a property called 'model1', but your json doesn't contain a property called 'model1'. Incidentally, the property called 'id' in your json will be ignored because BaeModel doesn't define such a property.

Comment: @ThomasKelly: The json will not contain property called model1. But it will contain properties a1 and a2. They are populating correctly in BaseModel class, but I am not able to get them in Model class.

Comment: You're casting to BaseModel - .ToObject<BaseModel>, so that is what will be created from the json. If you want to create a Model1 then do .ToObject<Model1>. Why does your BaseModel contain a Model1 property?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to "a1" in the Json doesn't directly map to List a1 in your class. You might need to modify your JSON structure to match your class structure, or you can create a custom JSON converter to handle this mapping.

Also when you create an instance of Model1 from the deserialized Json make sure that the Parent property in Model1 is set correctly. If it's not set, that could be why you're getting null values.